# Mongodb group and sum two arrays of similar data from aggregate facet

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am running queries that target different levels of social data and have got this working with some fairly large aggregate pipelines which then run inside a $facet. 
The results of the $facet section come out with two arrays I then want to combine. eg.

```
{
"first": [
    {
        "_id": {
            "name": "one",
            "_id": "1"
        },
        "date": [
            "2017-09-07T00:00:00.000Z"
        ],
        "data": [
            1000
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": {
            "name": "two",
            "_id": "2"
        },
        "date": [
            "2017-09-07T00:00:00.000Z"
        ],
        "data": [
            2000
        ]
    }
],
"second": [
    {
        "_id": {
            "name": "1",
            "_id": "one"
        },
        "date": [
            "2017-09-07T00:00:00.000Z"
        ],
        "data": [
            1000
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": {
            "name": "two",
            "_id": "2"
        },
        "date": [
            "2017-09-07T00:00:00.000Z"
        ],
        "data": [
            2000
        ]
    }
]
}
```

I would like to group these results together and add up the totals to end up with

```
[ {
    "_id": {
        "name": "1",
        "_id": "one"
    },
    "date": [
        "2017-09-07T00:00:00.000Z"
    ],
    "data": [
        2000
    ]
},{
    "_id": {
        "name": "2",
        "_id": "two"
    },
    "date": [
        "2017-09-07T00:00:00.000Z"
    ],
    "data": [
        4000
    ]
}]
```

I have a query that groups the individual responses to get them to this level but is missing something that allows me to merge across the two arrays. I have experimented with unwinding the first and second array but haven't been able to find a solution that combines the data across both arrays.

Any help, tips or knowledge greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've tried unwinding one array with the thought to group it then unwind the other as is a fairly standard solution, but as the data I am trying to pair is across both arrays this doesn't actually help grouping. I have unwound both arrays and that creates a bunch of duplication but is probably the only option as I can't run a group on the "first" and "second" arrays themselves, need to break the arrays out first.

Comment: Once they are broken out I still need to remove the wrapping object though as it obscures the path to the ids etc.
eg. first: { _id, date, data }, second: { _id, date, data }
The first and second flags are 'in the way' so to speak.

Comment: The group stage after the unwinding is where I'm held up I can write - 
 $group: {
        _id: {
          name: '$first._id.brand',
          _id: '$first._id._id',
        },
        date: { $push: '$first._id.date' },
      }
But obviously this doesn't also merge the data from second

Comment: You can try `db.collection_name.aggregate([{"$project":{"combine":{$concatArrays:["$first", "$second"]}}}, {"$unwind":"$combine"},
{"$group":{"_id":"$combine._id", 
"date":{"$first":{$arrayElemAt:["$combine.date", 0]}},"data":{"$sum":{$arrayElemAt:["$combine.data", 0]}}}}])`. You can better answer if you add your current aggregation query to avoid the values to end up as array in  the first place.

Comment: @Veeram The array concat you suggested does exactly what I need. If you want to turn it into an answer I will up vote it. I think you may be right about being able to adjust the query further up the aggregate chain but it's currently 2 9 stage pipelines wrapped in a facet and the facet produces the two arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$concatArrays` to merge arrays from `$facets` output followed by `$group` with `$arrayElemAt` to pick the first element for `$first` and `$sum` accumulator.

```
[
  {
    "$project": {
      "combine": {
        "$concatArrays": [
          "$first",
          "$second"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$combine"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$combine._id",
      "date": {
        "$first": {
          "$arrayElemAt": [
            "$combine.date",
            0
          ]
        }
      },
      "data": {
        "$sum": {
          "$arrayElemAt": [
            "$combine.data",
            0
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```